# How can I add custom attributes to a "Product" type in with JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a real estate website which displays real estate properties for sale. For each page where a property is listed, I want to create JSON-LD code to display information about the property, using Schema.org.

I am not sure if there is a better type to use than `Product` for real estate listings here.

How can I add a custom attribute to describe the property?

Here is a JSON-LD structure for `Product`:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "address of the property ",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "description": "description about the houese"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to add other info like

**Primary Features**

1. How many bedrooms it has
2. How many bathrooms it has
3. If it is a smart home or not
4. etc...

**Interior Features**

1. Fireplace
2. Fireplace location
3. etc...

**Exterior Features**

1. The Lots Size
2. Fets
3. etc...

How can I add these custom attribute that describes the property using Schema.org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide data about real estate, you need to use a type that represents real estate. Probably [`Accommodation`](https://schema.org/Accommodation) ([`Apartment`](https://schema.org/Apartment), [`House`](https://schema.org/House), …) for your case.

If you want to convey that this real estate is a product, you need to provide the `Product` type in addition to the `Accommodation` type.

Then you can use properties from `Accommodation` as well as `Product`.

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": ["House", "Product"],

  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer"
  },

  "numberOfRooms": 4

}
```

Custom properties about the real estate can be added with the [`additionalProperty`](https://schema.org/additionalProperty) property, and, if applicable, with the [`amenityFeature`](https://schema.org/amenityFeature) property.

Comment: The problem with `House` is that it does not allow for `Offers` or place to put a price for sale. On the other end, `Product` expect info like `priceValidUntil`, `review`, `brand`, `sku` and `gtin` which is not available in my case. I am wondering if there is a better schema to use for listing real estate properties for sale.

Comment: @MikeA: Not sure I get what you mean -- did you see that my snippet contains an `Offer` for the `House`? This `Offer` is the item that would get the price. -- And it’s perfectly fine to provide a `Product` only with the properties you want to provide -- Schema.org doesn’t require any properties.

Comment: Your answer is a great help. I am saying I wish the `house` type supports offers as an alternative solution.  Although, `priceValidUntil`, `review`, `brand`, `sku` and `gtin` are optional, I got the following message from Google. "Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 6 new Products related issues. This means that Products may be negatively affected in Google Search results. We encourage you to fix these issues. Missing field `priceValidUntil`
No global identifier provided (e.g., gtin, mpn, isbn), Missing field `review`, Missing field `brand`, and Missing field `sku`"

Comment: @MikeA: These Google errors are "only" for getting one of their rich results -- if you can’t (or don’t want to) provide the properties that Google requires, you won’t get the Product rich result, but nothing else happens.